# MVC radiobutton didn't call ActionResult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, action, actionresult

I'm trying to call ActionResult by using JQuery. And doing something wrong, because query starts, but ActionResult in controller - not. Also I need to send value of checked radiobutton in it.

JQuery:

```
    $("#allRows").on("change", function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "OrderManagment")';

        if ($("#allRows").attr("checked") === "checked") {
            $.post(url, { 'tableRows': $("#allRows").val() });
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Index( string tableRows )
        {
            //some code

            if (tableRows == "all")
            {
                return View(orders.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                var rows = Int32.Parse(_context.Settings.FirstOrDefault().Value);
                return View(orders.ToList().Take(rows));
            }
        }
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="Index">
 <div  style="text-align: right;">
        <label> Select count of rows in the table</label>
        <label><input type="radio" id="allRows" name="tableRows" value="all"> All</label>
        <label><input type="radio" id="settings" name="tableRows" value="settings" checked/> Settings </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your radio button with `id="allRows"` does not have a `checked` attribute. Use `if ($('#allRows').is(':checked')) { ...`

Comment: your also not doing anything with the view you return.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, for a little it works. Maybe I post  or send value in a wrong way? Still nothing happens with ActionResult.

Comment: Its difficult to understand what your trying to do here. Why are you calling a method every time the user selects the 1st radio button. And that method returns a view but you never do anything with that view. And what is the point of `if (tableRows == "all")` when the only value that ever gets posted is `"all"` (your `else` block will never be executed)

Comment: What is it your expecting to happen?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have a table and need to show rows number according to the settings. If checked radiobutton "All" will be shown all the table, if "Settings" - will be shown only first N rows (value stores in the DB).

Comment: You need to update the DOM in the success callback - `$.post(url, { 'tableRows': $("#allRows").val() }, function(response) { $('#someElement').html(response); });`. But again, you will only ever execute the `orders.ToList()` code and only when you click the 1st button

Comment: @StephenMuecke and how can I change the logic to do it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152053/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-antatrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#allRows").on("change", function () {
        var url = '@(Url.Action("Index", "OrderManagment"))';

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $.post(url, { tableRows: $("#allRows:checked").val() , function(data){
                alert(data );
            });
        }
    });
```